# how to bake rigid body?

Tags: mesh, rigid-body-simulation, smoke-simulation

so I have a rigid body simulation but the problem is I don't know exactly how to bake them , I have a plane with kind of explosion on (the plane is a loose part) on edit mode , I have two plane with loose parts on  , I don t know exactly how to explain it but basically I want to bake all the keyframe

the tutorial I have been following : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKiv6dKupoE&t=326s

[image]

Comment: Are they all animated already? It looks like that to me

Comment: i just never bake them? or never press the bake keyframe or something , but they are all running very slow thats why i want to bake them so i can atleast work on animation

Comment: What I mean is, are those objects animated already?

Comment: oh sorry , yes they are animated already

Comment: any suggestion please? best regard

Comment: If they are animated already and already have keyframes, you may not have to bake it, though I personally don't work very much with rigid bodies in Blender.